# Ruby on Rails: email_field has value inserted when page loads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, field

I have a field that takes in the users email

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

    <div class = "field">Email: 
      <%= f.email_field :email, :class => "email" %></div>

<% end %>
```

Every time I load the page, the email text box has a `'` inserted already, and the user has to delete it to insert their email properly.

When I expect the element using chrome. I can see that the value for the email field is is `"'"`. How do I delete it? Thanks in advance

EDIT:

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :username, :firstname, :lastname

  # attr_accessible :title, :body
end
```

Comment: Have you looked through any javascripts in your app for any cases where it would insert a value into a input field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should have a `form_for @user` (or similar) line above. The local variable is filled by your controller. Look at the controller code, if there is something that fills in the "'" or look at the model if there is a default, that sets the email field to "'".

To change the schema definition of the user data create a new db mirgration:

```
rails generate migration no_default_for_user_email
```

This will create a new file in /db/migrate with a migration definition with two functions:

```
def up
    change_column :users, 'email', :string, default: ""
end

def down
    change_column :users, 'email', :string, default: "'"
end
```

This should update your data base definition.

Comment: I am using the Devise gem. From what I understand, I don't have a controller for the Devise side of my app. I will post the model for you to see

Comment: @JamesMcL13 Have a look at the /db/schema.rb file. There should be a definition for the user table.

Comment: I found this line `t.string "email", :default => "'", :null => false`.
When I remove the `'` it reappears when I migrate the database

Comment: @JamesMcL13 You have to write a migration, that changes this default to ''.

Comment: Could you explain how to do this? Sorry, I am new to rails. Thanks

Comment: @JamesMcL13 I've added an example